# don't understand alignment symbols and how this piece of code works

Tags: python, python-3.x

im taking a summer course for python and came across this python code:

```
num1 = input( )  # input will be 10

num2 = input( )  # input will be 20

num3 = num1 + num2

print (f'The sum is {num3:<50}')
```

what does this last piece do inside the curly brace {num3: <50}? What does that <50 mean??

Any help appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Note that since the inputs are strings and your code doesn't convert them to `int`s or `float`s, adding them is actually going to concatenate the digits together, rather than doing numeric addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the value is left aligned within the given space of 50 chars which makes little sense if nothing is coming after:

```
>>> num3 = 3.14
>>> f'The sum is {num3:<50} hello')
'The sum is 3.14                                             hello'
```

From [the docs on string format syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) on `"<"`:

> Forces the field to be left-aligned within the available space (this is the default for most objects).